# i add facture for the user but when i try to add anothe factures it gives me an error

Tags: nestjs

here my  create method in my facture.service:

```
 async create(facture: CreateFactureDto, user: User): Promise<Facture> {
    const existingFactures = await this.factureModel.find({ code: user._id });
    if (existingFactures.length > 0) {
      return this.factureModel.create({
        ...facture,
        user: user._id,
      });
    }
    const createdFacture = await this.factureModel.create({
      ...facture,
      user: user._id,
    });
    await this.userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      user._id,
      { $push: { factures: createdFacture._id } },
      { new: true },
    );
    return createdFacture;
  }
```

here the controller:

```
  @Post()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  async create(
    @Body() body: CreateFactureDto,
    @Req() req,
  ): Promise<{ facture: Facture }> {
    const user = req.user._id;
    const facture = await this.factureService.create(body, user);
    console.log(facture);
    return { facture };
  }
```

here the createFacture dto:

```
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => User)
  @IsEmpty({ message: 'User ID should not be provided in the request body' })
  readonly user: User;
```

here user.schema:

```
@Prop({ type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Facture' }] })
  readonly factures: Facture[];
```

here facture.schema: @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })   user: User;

```
[Nest] 3260  - 20/03/2024, 13:44:26   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.factures index: userId.email_1 dup key: { userId.email: null }
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.factures index: userId.email_1 dup key: { userId.email: null }
    at InsertOneOperation.execute (C:\Users\asus\WebstormProjects\FullStackApp\piximind-back\node_modules\mongodb\src\operations\insert.ts:79:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at executeOperationAsync (C:\Users\asus\WebstormProjects\FullStackApp\piximind-back\node_modules\mongodb\src\operations\execute_operation.ts:190:12)
```